# Disable Sliding Drawer from opening

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

How do you disable a SlidingDrawer from opening by dragging its handle? I just want it to open when you click the handle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend SlidingDrawer and disable related event handler, e.g.

```
public class ClickOnlySlidingDrawer extends MySlidingDrawer {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and doing something like `drawer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         return false;
     }

     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         return false;
     }`

Comment: Tried your solution and it help, btw. Thanks! My previous question is just for me to learn.

Comment: the behavior of onInterceptTouchEvent is well documented in android sdk documents. you need to read that, it's difficult to describe it in simple comments.

Answer (score 1):

you can also lock the component and use .toggle instead like here

```
mySlidingDrawer.lock();  //  .unlock()
handle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mySlidingDrawer.toggle();

    }

});
```